# Get page id of a confluence page from its public url

Tags: python, python-3.x, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

How to get a Confluence `page_id` given a `page_url`. For Eg:

If this is the Display URL: https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page

I want to get its `page_id` using Confluence REST API

More details [here](https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page)

Comment: Give us a few example urls?

Comment: @nlta here is a link for reference https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use [atlassian-python-api](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html)?

In that case you can parse your url to get the confluence space (`SC`) and page title (`Finding the Page ID of a Confluence Page`) then use `confluence.get_page_id(space, title)`.

```
from atlassian import Confluence

page_url = "https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page"

confluence = Confluence(
        url='https://confluence.som.yale.edu/',
        username=user,
        password=pwd)
        
space, title = page_url.split("/")[-2:]
title = title.replace("+", " ")

page_id = confluence.get_page_id(space, title)
```

Note that when your title contains a special character (`+` or `ü`, `ä`...) your page url will already contain the id like this: `https://confluence.som.yale.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1234567890` so you might want to check for it first.

EDIT: here a version of what your function could look like:

```
from atlassian import Confluence
import re
import urllib

# regex pattern to match pageId if already in url
page_id_in_url_pattern = re.compile(r"\?pageId=(\d+)")

def get_page_id_from_url(confluence, url):
    page_url = urllib.parse.unquote(url) #unquoting url to deal with special characters like '%'
    space, title = page_url.split("/")[-2:]

    if re.search(page_id_in_url_pattern, title):
        return re.search(page_id_in_url_pattern, title).group(1)
    
    else:
        title = title.replace("+", " ")
        return confluence.get_page_id(space, title)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    from getpass import getpass
    user = input('Login: ')
    pwd = getpass('Password: ')

    page_url = "https://confluence.som.yale.edu/display/SC/Finding+the+Page+ID+of+a+Confluence+Page"

    confluence = Confluence(
            url='https://confluence.som.yale.edu/',
            username=user,
            password=pwd)

    print(get_page_id_from_url(confluence, page_url))
```

Comment: Yes this is the only way AFAIK. Thanks for your answer.
I will wait for some more time until I accept this answer, coz what I am precisely looking for is an API that can give the page_id and details from its page_url.

Comment: Is it sure that all blank space characters " " in URL will be replaced by a "+"?

Comment: whitespaces always seem to be replaced by "+". The API doesn't seem to offer such a function. I wrote one that should work in most cases. check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Atlassian Python client is very limited (e.g. there is no way to access tiny URLs from page share links). If you get an API key you could hypothetically make some REST calls to download the headers of any arbitrary page and grab the pageId from that.

If you are using the Python client however, you can only get pageId from a URL if it is 1) already in the URL or 2) you have a properly-formatted spaceKey and title in the URL.

Building on [the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69550972/4227970) that [Tranbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13525512/tranbi) provided, here is an improved function that attempts to extract the pageId from a URL. It does not work for all URLs though, be warned.

```py
from atlassian import Confluence
import re
import urllib


CONFLUENCE_HOSTNAME = 'confluence.som.yale.edu'

PAGEID_RE = re.compile(r"pageId=(\d+)")
SPACEKEY_RE = re.compile(r"spaceKey=([a-zA-Z0-9~]+)")
TITLE_RE = re.compile(r"title=([^#&=]+)")


def get_pageid_from_url(client, raw_url):
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urllib.parse.urlparse(raw_url)
    if netloc != CONFLUENCE_HOSTNAME:
        raise ValueError(f"Only Confluence URLs are supported in this script. You supplied a URL with netloc={netloc}")

    # Special handling for login redirect URLs
    fix_title = False
    if path == '/login.action':
        fix_title = True
        pretty_url = urllib.parse.unquote(raw_url) #unquoting url to deal with special characters like '%'
        scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urllib.parse.urlparse(pretty_url)

    # Get the pageId directly from the URL if available
    pageid_match = re.search(PAGEID_RE, query)
    if pageid_match:
        return pageid_match.group(1)

    # Otherwise, get the spaceKey and title from the URL, and then make a separate call to the API to get the pageId
    if path.startswith('/display/'):
        path_pieces = path.split('/')
        assert len(path_pieces) == 4, f"Expected 4 forward-slashes in path, but found {path}"
        _, _, space, title = path_pieces
        # Fix title; order of operations matters!
        title = title.replace("+", " ")
        title = urllib.parse.unquote(title, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
        return client.get_page_id(space, title)
    spacekey_match = re.search(SPACEKEY_RE, query)
    title_match = re.search(TITLE_RE, query)
    if spacekey_match and title_match:
        space = spacekey_match.group(1)
        # Fix title; order of operations matters!
        title = title_match.group(1)
        title = title.replace("+", " ")
        if fix_title:
            title = title.split(' - ')[0]
        title = urllib.parse.unquote(title, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
        return client.get_page_id(space, title)

    # Unfortunately this URL style is not supported by the Python Atlassian client :(
    raise ValueError(f"Cannot parse (pageId) or (spaceKey and title) from URL: {raw_url}")
```